# PHP associative group

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. Can anyone tell how to arrange the following associative array to this using a function?

```
$ownerfiles =  ["Input.txt" => "Randy", "Code.py" => "Stan", "Output.txt" => "Randy"];
$ownerfiles = ["Randy" => ["Input.txt", "Output.txt"], "Stan" => ["Code.py"]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested the code below, it works. I made it as short as possible.

```
$ownerfiles = ["Input.txt" => "Randy", "Code.py" => "Stan", "Output.txt" => "Randy"]; 
foreach ($ownerfiles as  $key => $value) {
    $new_arr[$value][]=$key;
}
print_r($new_arr);
// Output: 
//Array ( [Randy] => Array ( [0] => Input.txt [1] => Output.txt ) [Stan] => Array ( [0] => Code.py ) )
```

Comment: Thanks, if it answers your question, you can Check this answer.